# Avoiding DLL versioning problems

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have multiple executable programs in C++ which use many libraries written also in C++ (I have the sources of all of them).

The problem I'm facing is: when an executable EXE includes a dll DLL they might both depend on additional dlls DLL1 and DLL2:

```
EXE ----- DLL
 |         |
 DLL1      DLL2
```

if DLL1 and DLL2 are **the same library** and DLL2 is a more up-to-date version of DLL1, I will have troubles linking and compiling stuff.

How can I solve this problem? Sometimes I can't just dump DLL1 and keep the most up-to-date due to backward compatibility problems.

Comment: Personally, my recommendation is to avoid the whole mess and just recompile your programs into stand-alone executables.  Yeah, they'll take up a little bit more disk space, but these days, who cares?

Comment: Given you have the source for everything - rather than my complex answer below - the pragmatic solution would be to rebuild the dll's including version numbers. Then exe would import and use "dll.1.0.dll, and dll would import and use 'dll.2.0.dll' and everyone could exist in one folder.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft solved this problem for Windows XP but has pretty much concealed the information on how to do it from "native" developers.

The somewhat intimidating MSDN page [Building C/C++ Isolated Applications and Side-by-side Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235532.aspx) is the jumping off point to this.

Essentially what you will do is:

1. Convert Dll1 and Dll2 into assemblies. An assembly is a dll file + a manifest that owns it. Call them dll1.manifest and dll2.manifest (perhaps).
2. Add manifestdependency* directives to EXE and DLL which list each of the above assemblies by name.
3. Create sub folders "dll1" and "dll2" for each assembly and store the indentically named dlls therein.

Note: that "dll" and "exe" do not, themselves need to be assemblies although the documentation might infer / encourage that.

---

With regards to step 2 - it is not necessary to manually add or merge manifest files for the exe or dll, as modern versions of Visual Studio automatically include generated manifests with applications. There is an entire project settings tab dedicated to this.

To hook into this a DevStudio #pragma is used to register assemblies to be included in the generated manifest. This is an example of how an application (or dll) would declare its interest in using the versioned version of comctl32.dll - for your purposes you would change the name to reflect your "dll" assembly names, and you won't need the version or publicKeyToken parameters for assemblies that accompany your app.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
  name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
  processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```